# What is the small hole on the top of the pixel 3a?

Tags: google-pixel

Many [reviews](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/05/google-pixel-3a-hands-on-the-best-parts-of-the-pixel-for-half-the-price/) note the pixel 3a has a headphone jack on top. Yes, I like it, too.  But I can't find anywhere that describes the other little hole, the one on the right in [this picture](https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Pixel-3a-4-980x735.jpg).  What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [specs for the Pixel 3a](https://store.google.com/product/pixel_3a_specs) and open up the Media & Audio section you'll see:

> Stereo speakers
>
> 2 microphones
>
> Noise suppression

The small holes are for microphones, usually multiple ones are used to improve call quality, i.e. suppressing background noise.